# Java StringReader reads beyond input. Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Tags: java, stringreader

Try this code -

```
import java.io.StringReader;

public class StringReaderTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String sampleString = "abcdefg";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(sampleString);

        for(int i=0; i<40; i++)
        {
            char c = (char) reader.read();
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is -

```
abcdefg?????????????????????????????????
```

So the reader actually read past the end of the input. I was under the impression that it should have thrown an exception when it tried to read beyond "g", but it did not. It instead returned a "?" character. Is this a bug or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29) is quite clear in this case:

> `StringReader.read()`
>
> **Returns:** The character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So -1 is printed as a ?

Comment: you're casting -1 to a char which returns '?'

Comment: char myChar = (char) -1; System.out.println(myChar);

Answer (score 2):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29 StringReader.Read() returns -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. It doesn't throw an IOException unless there's some other sort of error.